# Small size image is end up in large size after uploading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When i am uploading image of 400KB it ends up getting 1.3MB

```
    $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
    $image_type = 'project_thumbnail';

    $destinationPath = 'assets/images/projects/'.$project_id;
    $filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = time().'_'.$filename;
    $extension = $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $photo = $request->file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $photo= Image::make($destinationPath.'/'.$filename);
    $photo->resize(1024, 683, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save();
    $media = new \App\Media(['type'=>$image_type, 'filename'=>$filename, 'path'=>$destinationPath.'/'.$filename, 'thumbnail_path'=>$destinationPath.'/'.$filename,'extension'=>$extension]);
    $project->media()->save($media);
    return 1;
```

but if i upload 1.3MB image file its not changing at all

Thank you in advance.

Edit1

I tried

```
    $photo->resize(null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save();
```

also

```
    $photo= Image::make($destinationPath.'/'.$filename)->save();
    // $photo->resize(1024, 683, function ($constraint) {
    //   $constraint->aspectRatio();
    // })->save();
```

but seems nothing working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you are resizing your image before saving.

```
$photo->resize(1024, 683, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save();
```

Resizing changes the size of image.

So what problably happens is that your initial image, which weights 400KB has smaller resolution than 1024. Then you change resolution to 1024, which increases its size to 1.3MB.

Then you upload the 1.3MB image, which already has resolution 1024, so it isn't changed by `resize()` and its size stays and 1.3MB.

Comment: I have tried removing resize thing, but same thing is happening.